# Convert MS Access Crosstab to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm trying to convert the following Access Crosstab query to work in SQL Server 2008 (that does not support Transform & Pivot). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
TRANSFORM Last(dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex.FAIL_CODE) AS LastOfFAIL_CODE1
SELECT dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex.SERIAL_ID
FROM dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex
WHERE (((dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex.TEST_DATE)>#7/1/2013 0:0:1#) AND ((dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex.TEST_RESULT)="fail"))
GROUP BY dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex.SERIAL_ID
PIVOT dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex.TEST_AREA In ("Test_1","Test_2","Test_3","Test_4","Test_5","Test_6");
```

Thanks.

If a test is run multiple times, can I pull the last Fail_code result for each (test_1, Test_2...ect) based on max date?  I have a field called TEST_DATE and I want to pull the last record for each test.  If a test passes or is not run, the field FAIL_CODE will be NULL.  Here is the raw data that I want to do the pivot on.

```
TEST_AREA TEST_DATE              SERIAL_ID  TEST_RESULT  FAIL_CODE
Test_1    8/14/2013 11:29:24 AM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_2    8/17/2013 08:49:35 AM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_3    8/17/2013 10:13:41 PM  12398701   FAIL         Pwr_up
Test_3    8/17/2013 10:15:38 PM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_4    8/17/2013 10:23:22 PM  12398701   FAIL         Pwr_up
Test_4    8/17/2013 10:24:22 PM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_5    8/18/2013 07:34:34 AM  12398701   FAIL         Memory_1
```

Here is the current result when I run the SQL provided by user bluefeet.

```
SERIAL_ID  Test_1  Test_2  Test_3   Test_4  Test_5    Test_6
12398701   NULL    NULL    Pwr_up   Pwr_up  Memory_1  NULL
```

As you can see in the raw data – Test_3 anf Test_4 were ran twice.
The second time Test_3 and Test_4 were ran they passed so I don’t want to report the first failure.  Here is my desired output.

```
SERIAL_ID  Test_1  Test_2  Test_3  Test_4  Test_5    Test_6
12398701   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Memory_1  NULL
```

Comment: SQL2008 does support PIVOT

Comment: I have rolled back the changes to this question, please post a new question with the new requirements. [Ask Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @JimA please **[make a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)**, do not edit this one.

Comment: @JimA As I said and others you need to post a new question.  Also you state that you want to display the item that is later but all of your data for `Test_3` and `Test_4` are from the exact same date/time there is no way to distinguish which one is older.  These are the types of details you should be posting in a **[new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does support [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) just not with the TRANSFORM syntax, your query would be similar to the following:

```
select SERIAL_ID, Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6
from
(
    select SERIAL_ID, FAIL_CODE, TEST_AREA
    from dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex
    where TEST_DATE> '2013-07-01' 
        AND TEST_RESULT='fail'
) d
pivot
(
    max(FAIL_CODE)
    for TEST_AREA in (Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6)
) piv;
```

SQL Server does not support the `LAST()` function that MS Access uses. You will need to use an aggregate function of `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `COUNT`, or `SUM`, etc to get the result.

Your new requirements are not very clear and there is no clear way to determine which row is later since you have the same date/time for each entry but you might be able to use:

```
select SERIAL_ID, Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6
from
(
  select f1.SERIAL_ID, f1.FAIL_CODE, f1.TEST_AREA
  from dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex f1
  where f1.TEST_DATE> '2013-07-01' 
    AND f1.TEST_RESULT='fail'
    and not exists (select test_area
                    from dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex f2
                    where f2.TEST_DATE> '2013-07-01' 
                      and f2.TEST_RESULT<>'fail'
                      and f1.TEST_DATE = f2.TEST_DATE
                      and f1.TEST_AREA = f2.TEST_AREA)
) d
pivot
(
    max(FAIL_CODE)
    for TEST_AREA in (Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6)
) piv;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93f91/10)

After your last edit with time included on the date you should be able to use:

```
select SERIAL_ID, Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6
from
(
  select SERIAL_ID, FAIL_CODE, TEST_AREA
  from
  (
    select f1.SERIAL_ID, f1.FAIL_CODE, f1.TEST_AREA, f1.TEST_RESULT,
      row_number() over(partition by f1.SERIAL_ID, f1.TEST_AREA
                        order by f1.TEST_DATE desc) seq
    from dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex f1
    where f1.TEST_DATE> '2013-07-01' 
  ) d
  where seq = 1
    and TEST_RESULT='fail'
) d
pivot
(
    max(FAIL_CODE)
    for TEST_AREA in (Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6)
) piv;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb1ba/6)

Comment: @JimA Right that is how you write a PIVOT.  The `Test_1`, etc are the values that will be converted to columns

Comment: @JimA If you have a new question, then you should post a new question with those details and requirements.

Comment: sorry, I was trying to learn how to format my response. Each record has a unique test date/time (I lost the time when formating my post)

Comment: Is there a way to have the output for each TEST_AREA that is NULL and does not have TEST_RESULT = PASS or FAIL (no record) display INC?

Comment: @JimA My suggestion would be to Ask a New question with the new reuqirements.